# ¿Cómo hacer un Insert masivo de datos a alta velocidad en una base de datos SQL?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, pandas, spark

Estoy trabajando con un dataset de aproximadamente 1.000.000 de registro, con algunas trasformaciones básicas en panda con python, para luego cargarlas a una base de datos sql(mysql y postgresql).

Las trasformaciones en pandas se hacen en menos de un minuto, pero el insert en la db tarda mas de una hora.

hay alguna técnica o herramienta para poder hacer el registro en la db a mayor velocidad ?

He realizado un curso introductorio a spark pero no me ha quedado claro si esto herramienta me puede ayudar a cumplir con la tarea de procesar el insert a mayor velocidad.

Me serviría mucho cualquier comentario sobre el tema.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de implementación masiva es el siguiente basado en un evento activadando la opción de `cursor.fast_executemany = True` para ejecuciones múltiples:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
from urllib.parse import quote_plus


conn =  "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=IP_ADDRESS;DATABASE=DataLake;UID=USER;PWD=PASS"
quoted = quote_plus(conn)
new_con = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)
engine = create_engine(new_con)


@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    print("FUNC call")
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True


table_name = 'fast_executemany_test'
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10**4, 100)))


s = time.time()
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists = 'replace', chunksize = None)
print(time.time() - s)
```